# Budget android phone with proper autofocus(<$200)

Tags: android, camera

I'm looking for a half-decent android phone with an emphasis on camera quality and autofocus. The main reason I want a cheap phone like this is for scanning 2D barcodes(Not QR Codes) with the camera. I have an application I use which uses the back facing camera to detect and scan barcodes, however, the budget phone i've tried so far has not worked at all in that respect, as the autofocus does not appear to properly provide enough quality to recognize the barcode.

The phone I tried to use for this purpose is the Alcatel Boost View 5.0 which was $99. It was advertised with a 5MP back camera with autofocus, however, simply does not work with the scanning of barcodes.

I should also mention that i'm on kind of a budget, and the phone i'm looking for ideally will be under $150 but if that's not possible I can go above that.

The phones i've been looking at to solve this problem are the Samsung Galaxy Core Prime and Samsung Galaxy J1 Ace. These phones are in the $150-$250 price range, but i'm not sure if they solve my problem, and i'm not sure if there is a cheaper alternative.

Can anyone shed some light on this whole camera quality autofocus thing and maybe help me out with a recommendation?

Comment: try "barcode scanner" by zxing in the app store first, of the apps I have tested it locks on faster gets reading when others can't.

Comment: If you want a good camera in that budget I'd go for a used flagship. Where I live you can easily get, say, LG G3 for around 100 USD. Sadly if camera matters used flagships top anythning new you can buy.